# How to calculate price of gas

Tags: transactions, protocol, gas, fee, burn

In Ethereum one can get the gas price using **web3.eth.gasPrice**.

In Tezos, does any RPC provide the gas price, or is there a formula to calculate the gas price?

Answer (score 4):

In Tezos, gas does not have a monetary translation. It does not "cost" you anything to execute a contract with 10 gas vs 1M gas. Gas is simply an internal limitation to prevent contracts from running amok.

https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/psa-do-not-quote-gas-cost-in-tez/1618

Answer (score 3):

After asking, there is no equivalent of a gas price in Tezos. You pay a transaction fee, and this fee should include everything. Doing some stats on the fees you may get an upper-bound on the gas price.

Comment: How do you actually find this price through either an API call to a block explorer or an RPC call to a Tezos node?

Comment: tzstats provides an API that will give you statistics on created blocks. They provide for example an average gas price which is just total_paid_fees_in_the_block / total_used_gas_in_the_block. This means that this average gas price depends on what people proposed as fees what bakers accepted.